# Replacing fan/light with 2 wall with fan/light controlled by remote

Tags: wiring, switch, fans

I am replacing an old fan that runs off 2 wall switches. Switch 1 controls the light.  Switch 2 controls the fan.

The new fan has remote only. The power source is 2 wire (Black, White, Bare).  The remote has Black, white, Blue and Yellow wires. I cannot get the remote to control both the light and the fan.  What would be the proper wiring to make sure the remote controls both light & Fan with at least 1 wall switch on?

Comment: This will be a LOT easier if we have (a) the model # of the new fan/light so we can see the installation instructions, which should explain the colored wires and (b) a picture of the wires going to the switch(es).

Comment: Hunter Designer Series OmiCron Ceiling Fan 54" Remote Intertek Remote 3177973.  Old fan wiring: Ceiling Black to Fan Black.  Ceiling White to Fan Blue.  Ceiling Bare to Grounds and Fan White.

Comment: Oh no! That means that in the old system you were bootlegging neutral to ground! You can't do that! That's how you got an "extra" wire up there before. Definitely needs some rework...

Comment: Blame that on the one who calls himself the fan man.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Is running a new cable from the wall switch location to the fan location an option?  Do you still want wall-switch control of the fan, lights, or both? How much do you care about using the remote?

Comment: I took a quick look and this is apparently a Lowe's exclusive. No manual on the Lowe's site (Home Depot tends to better on that) and no info. at all on Hunter. But looking at other Hunter fans, it looks like you can do one switch for everything together and use the remote for separate control, but not 100% clear.

Comment: I have the manual and of that.  I would prefer not to run a new line and opeartet eh light from a switch and the fan from the remote to control speed.  The instructions are easy, but the situation is witht he way the original fan was wired.  Instruction for installation are:  Ceiling black to Remote Black.  Fan Black to Remote Yellow.  Ceiling White to Remote & Fan White.  Fan Blue to Remote Blue (light).  Only the light will work from switch.  Fan does not work with switch or remote in this scenario.

Comment: Is a new wire the only solution?  THe fan needs the remote because there is no way to control the speed.  Can I do something to the orginal switch (SW1 - light) of the new switch (SW2 - fan) that was installed 10 yhears ago?